# How to call an implemented interface method with different return types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've an interface that has one method with an Interface return type.
Is there a way to implement that method in different classes with different return types (derived from the interface return type)?

This is my code so far...

```
public interface IMainRepository
{
    IMyForm GetForm();
}

public interface IMyForm 
{
    SomeCustomObject myCustomObject { get; set; }
}

public class SecondForm : IMyForm 
{
    public SomeCustomObject myCustomObject { get; set; }
    public AnotherCustomObject anotherCustomObject { get; set; }
}
public class ThirdForm : IMyForm 
{
    public SomeCustomObject myCustomObject { get; set; }
    public ThisIsAnotherCustomObject thisIsAnotherCustomObject { get; set; }
}
public class SecondRepository : IMainRepository
{
    public IMyForm GetForm() 
    {
        var SecondForm form = new SecondForm();
        //Do stuff...
        return form;
    }
}

public class ThirdRepository : IMainRepository
{
    public IMyForm GetForm() 
    {
        var ThirdForm form = new ThirdForm();
        //Do stuff...
        return form;
    }
}
```

Having this.. can I make some modification so I can get something like this?

```
public class FormController : ApiController 
{
    private readonly IMainRepository mainRepository;

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Http.Route(APIRoutes.GET_SECOND_FORM)]           
        public SecondForm GetSecondFormData()
        {           
            return mainRepository.GetForm<SecondForm>();
        }

        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Http.Route(APIRoutes.GET_THIRD_FORM)]
        public ThirdForm GetThirdFormData()
        {
            return mainRepository.GetForm<ThirdForm>();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is actually a code smell. The generic shape of `GetForm` implies that I could call it with any `IMyForm`, but that will not be possible, because you will have implemented the method only for specific forms. What if I create a new custom IMyForm for example and call your generic method -> *Crack*.

```
public TForm GetForm<TForm>() where TForm : IMyForm, class
{
    // If you do something like this, it's probably a code smell...
    if (typeof(TForm) == typeof(FirstForm)) // return some first form
}
```

If you really really want that generic method, you could play around with reflection to find types that match the specified type for `TForm`, but I would not recommend it, because it causes a lot of complexity.

I'd suggest going the easy way and providing methods called `GetFirstForm`, `GetSecondForm`, etc.

```
public interface IMainRepository
{
    FirstForm GetFirstForm();
    SecondForm GetSecondForm();
    // etc.
}
```

Or using `IMainRepository<TForm>` and having multiple repository fields in your controller.

```
public interface IMainRepository<TForm> where TForm : IMyForm, class
{
    TForm GetForm();
}

public class SecondRepository : IMainRepository<SecondForm>
{
    public SecondForm GetForm() 
    {
        var SecondForm form = new SecondForm();
        //Do stuff...
        return form;
    }
}

public class FormController : ApiController 
{
    private readonly IMainRepository<FirstForm> firstFormRepository;
    private readonly IMainRepository<SecondForm> secondFormRepository;

    // etc.
}
```